# How to add a object list as a property in a class?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a form, that form has a gridview that display data, that data comes from a list of any class that a I have in the entities, my question is how to add a list of any entity as property, i try the following:

```
    public List<T> objectList { get; set; } //List as entity
    public help() //Constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gridControlHelp.DataSource = objectList; //Binding the grid with the list
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiOcd.png)

Comment: Put an appropriate type for `T`.

Comment: To use `List<T>` generically like that in your `Form` subclass, the subclass itself needs to be generic so you can use the type parameter for the property. See duplicate for how to do that. Note that generic `Form` subclasses don't always "play well" with the Winforms Designer. So expect a little more head-scratching if you go down this path.